# при выводе данных из sql server через php не выводит кириллицу

Tags: php, sql-server

Подключил библиотеки для работы с sql server, скачанные с сайта майкрософт, подключаюсь к базе, вывожу данные, все хорошо, но только вот вместо кириллицы выводятся знаки вопроса. Всё уже облазил, не могу найти решение проблемы

Comment: Текст может быть в разных кодировках — одни и те же буквы могут быть заданы разными последовательностями бит. Узнайте в какой кодировке хранит ваш текст база и как сделать так, чтобы получить данные в utf8 (скорее всего вы используете utf8).

Comment: уже решил проблему. как изначально и догадывался из-за кодировки. меняю кодировку, когда получаю данные

Comment: Можно ли проблему в корне решить, пересохранив базу(windows-1251) в базу(utf-8) на SQL Server 19(поддерживает utf-8)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в кодировке данных. Таблицы была в `Cyrillic_General_CI_AS`. Судя по информации в интернете, *SQL Server* не поддерживает `UTF-8`, но, как я понял, если бы данные в БД были типа `nvarchar`, то проблем не было бы.

собственно проблему решил одной строчкой в php:

```
$var = iconv('windows-1251','UTF-8', $str);
```

Comment: Sql Server [UTF-8 support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver16#utf8)